# Adding Values of Field in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to ask you how I can add values of a array in C.
Example:

```
Array[5]
--------
Array[1]=0.2
Array[2]=0.2 ----> I want to add the first 0.2 to the second 0.2 (=0.4)
Array[3]=0.3
Array[4]=0.15
```

I want following output:

```
0.2
0.4
0.7
0.85
```

How can I do that? Special operators?
PS: I want to do that in a simple for loop. Not extra libaries etc.

Comment: There is no Array[5] element. You have elements from 0 to 4.

Comment: double val = 0.2; double* arr = malloc( sizeof( double ) * 5 ); memset( arr, val, 5 ); That should do it.

Comment: @Ben: I didn't see any evidence of them asking for a dynamic array.

Comment: @GeorgeT It's probably faster, though. I mean it works either way.

Comment: @Ben That won't work. `memset` works only with bytes.

Comment: double val = 0.2; double* arr = malloc( sizeof( double ) * 5 ); std::set( arr, val, 5 );

Answer (score 6):

Much fail. So many error.

Tag your question `[C]` *or* `[C++]`, but not both.
They are not the same thing.

If you declare `Array[5]`, then valid indicies are `0` through `4`.
`Array[5]` is **out of bounds**.

You describe wanting output, but your program has no output!
Show a `printf`, or `cout`, or similar output statement.

If you want to add a value to an array member, it is simple:

```
Array[2] = Array[2] + 0.2;
```

If you want to add two array members together:

```
Array[2] = Array[1] + Array[2];
```

Although you did not specify clearly, it looks like you want to make each member of the array be the sum of all the earlier members (including itself).

Here's my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    double array[] = { 0.2,
                       0.2,
                       0.3,
                       0.15
                     };

    for(int i=1; i<4; ++i)
    {
        array[i] += array[i-1];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        printf("[%d] : %lf\n", i, array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fair answer. Your `printf` needs an `i` though.

Comment: +1 for c and c++ not being the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can do this by using the range based for statement

```
double Array[5] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.15, 0.4 };

double sum = 0.0;

for ( double x : Array ) sum += x;
```

If you need to add outputing of intermediate sums then you can write the code above as

```
double Array[5] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.15, 0.4 };

double sum = 0.0;

for ( double x : Array ) 
{ 
    sum += x;
    std::cout << sum << ' ';
}
```

Or you can apply standard algorithm `std::accumulate` For example

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

//...

double Array[5] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.15, 0.4 };

double sum = std::accumulate( std::begin( Array ), std::end( Array ), 0.0 );
```

If you need only output partial sums then you can use standard algorithm `std::partial_sum` For example

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

//...

double Array[5] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.15, 0.4 };

std::partial_sum( std::begin( Array ), std::end( Array ), 
                  std::ostream_iterator<double>( std::cout, " " ) );
```

Or you can write a loop yourself. For example

```
double Array[5] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.15, 0.4 };

double sum = 0.0;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( Array ) / sizeof( *Array ); i++ ) sum += Array[i];
```

This loop you can use also in C.

The same code with outputing using C function printf

```
double Array[5] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.15, 0.4 };

double sum = 0.0;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( Array ) / sizeof( *Array ); i++ ) 
{
    sum += Array[i];
    printf( "%f ", sum );
}
```

In C you can also write your own algorithm for arrays of type double. For example

```
double Accumulate( const double a[], size_t n )
{
   double sum = 0.0;

   for ( const double *p = a; p < a + n; ++p ) sum += *p;

   return sum;
}
```

It can be called the following way

```
double Array[5] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.15, 0.4 };

double sum = Accumulate( Array, sizeof( Array ) / sizeof( *Array ) );;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
 Array[i]=Array[i]+Array[i+1];
 cout<< Array[i];
}
```

I dont quit know if you want it in c or c++(this one is in c++)
I also didnt add the namespace `std` and didnt include the `iostream` just the loop.

And you need to keep in mind that an array starts at 0 and not at 1, that why i start the loop with 0.